# Не получается организовать структуру папок в Silex

Tags: php, namespace, silex, php7

Пытаюсь организовать структуру папок в Silex приложении.

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app['autoloader'] = $loader;
$loader->add('Core', __DIR__ . '/../src');
$loader->add('Core\services', __DIR__ . '/../src/services');

$app['subscriber_service'] = $app->share(function() {
    return new Core\services\Subscriber();
});
```

Subscriber.php находится в ../src/services/

```
namespace Core\services;

class Subscriber 
{

}
```

При попытке вызвать new Core\services\Subscriber(); ловлю Not Found Exception.
Кроме Yii2 нигде с namespace на работал, а в yii вообще все просто и не задумываешься об автозагрузке. Подскажите, как правильно организовать структуру приложения на Silex и автозагрузку классов.

**UPD**
Посмотрел var_dump($loader) после добавления неймспесов. Для неймспейсов фреймворка вижу пути, а для своих вот это, без путей

```
'C' =>
array(2) {
  'Core' =>
  array(1) {
    ...
  }
  'Core\services' =>
  array(1) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**UPD 2**
Добавил в composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Core\\": "src/"}
}
```

Теперь классы подгружаются, но хотелось бы иметь возможность добавлять неймспейсы через PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить лоадер по стандарту PSR-4

```
$loader->addPsr4('Core', __DIR__ . '/../src');
```

а методом `$loader->add()` добвляется PSR-0 лоадер